# mysql update dynamic column name

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to UPDATE a table where the column name is a variable so it can be specified through iteration of an array that holds column names.  For example:

```
UPDATE my_table
    SET $column_name=$foo
    WHERE something=$bar
```

The SET syntax is the problem.  I've tried building a query up by concatenation but the nested quote marks are messing me up. The hard wired column specification works.

Here is the actual query i'm trying to build in a version that does not generate a PHP error but fails somewhere.  The idea is to SET column $v to the letter N (simplified detail) in table baccess.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE baccess SET " . $v . "=N
WHERE studentid=$_SESSION[student_id]") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Thanks

Comment: Is it really a requirement to have such a dynamic column name?

Comment: The reason I think I need it is that the column names are generated through user interaction.  For example, a lesson is created with a filename lesson1.  When a student is given a choice of which courses to enroll in, they checkbox select lesson1, lesson2, lessonN.  The table has a column for each lesson and each row has a studentid column and the date of enrollment in lesson1 in the lesson1 column.

Comment: Well, what problem are you facing while trying the SQL query you mentioned? I mean, did you get any error? If yes then what?

Comment: i've tried many different things, usually ending up in no error and no value stored.  I suspect that the real problem is my schema.  I got into this dilemma because I was trying to make a normalized database.  My instinct was to just store class names in an array and store the array in a table but was convinced not to break this rule.

Comment: Try enclosing the column name in backticks `UPDATE baccess SET [here]" . $v . "[here]=N WHERE ...`